# What HTTP response codes does the jQuery aJax error handler consider an 'error'?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a standard aJax call back to the server:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '/Apps/ResetDateAndCount',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            appName: app
        }),
        success: function (response) {
            $('.lastReset').text(response);
            $('.currentCount').text('0');
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
            alert("You are not authorized to perform that action");
        }
    });
```

From my server (ASP.NET) I am returning errors like:

```
return Json(new { success = false, error = "You are not authorized to perform that action" });
```

and

```
Response.StatusCode = 401; return Json(new { success = false, error = "You are not authorized to perform that action" });
```

and

```
Response.StatusCode = 500; return Json(new { success = false, error = "You are not authorized to perform that action" });
```

Inside of the error handler `error: function (xhr, status, error)` **only the last return will be caught as an error, when the status code is set to `500`.**

I am wondering what response codes aJax actually consider an "error"?

Comment: It should be any 4xx or 5xx error, with some exceptions, such as 401 (which would usually prompt the user to enter credentials, only causing an error if they cancel).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Any error code that is outside of the interval [200, 299] and different than 304 is considered an error by `jQuery` when making an AJAX call.

Now of course you're gonna ask me, that's fine and dandy but why the hell this is not considered as an error, after all I am returning 401 which outside of the aforementioned interval so it should be considered an error:

```
Response.StatusCode = 401; 
return Json(new { success = false, error = "You are not authorized to perform that action" });
```

Very simple: because when you return a 401 status code from a controller action in ASP.NET MVC, the framework (and more specifically the ASP.NET Forms Authentication module) will intercept this request and redirect you to the login form eventually resulting in a 200 status code. Yeah, the login page is served with a 200 OK status code. In this case 200 is inside the interval so no `error` callback is invoked. You can validate this by inspecting the DOM of the login page returned in your `success` callback for this particular case.

Now put yourself into the perspective of a browser making an AJAX request: **It will follow all the redirects** that a server makes until it reaches the final destination. If this final destination status code is outside of the interval and different than 304 then you will get the `error` callback invoked. OK, now things start to make a little more sense.

So the next question you're gonna ask me is how do I invoke the error callback if I return a 401 status code from my controller action, right? Then I will redirect you (:-)) to the following blog post: [`Prevent Forms Authentication Login Page Redirect When You Don't Want It`](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/04/prevent-forms-authentication-login-page-redirect-when-you-donrsquot-want.aspx/).

Comment: Very nice expanation (+1). However I have a question, status codes of the form 3xx are considered errors? I am asking because I think that they aren't errors.

Comment: No, no, no. Read my answer once again. And most importantly the **bolded** part of it. Let me repeat it once again: **It will follow all the redirects**, so basically there's no such notion as a `3xx` status code when you are making an AJAX call. What matters is the **final destination** status code. You can make millions of redirects but eventually you will end up serving some HTML with a status code 200, or crash like crap with status code 5xx because your server doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you :) !

Comment: That makes things much more clear.. thanks for the explanation

Comment: good info, but not accurate. while you were writing this i was actually looking at the jquery source code because i was curous what the answer really was. from the jQuery source code: `isSuccess = status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304;` anything that is not between 200 and 300 is an error except for 304.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking the list of standard HTTP codes. Please see it here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes. It's self-explanatory.

In other words, any codes >= 400 (4xx, 5xx) can be considered as an error.

You are returning the error message:
`"You are not authorized to perform that action"`

I'd say, this text message corresponds mostly to 401/403 codes. For 5xx errors, I would suggest you display some server error message.