# How do I handle a JQuery/AJAX error response?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Probably it is very simple but I can't figure out how to handle the jQuery/AJAX error

I've managed to submit a form with AJAX, it works perfectly except I can't catch and display the error(s) as I would like.

The response is under the form of JsonResponse and returns this array with all the errors (can be one or multiple)
`{error: {account_number: ["Account with this Account number already exists."]}}`

I would like to display in a div all the errors but the following code doesn't work

```js
$("#form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // serialize the data for sending the form data.
  var serializedData = $(this).serialize();
  // make POST ajax call
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "ajax_call.php",
    data: serializedData,
    success: function(response) {
      alert('Done!')
    },
    error: function(response) {
      // alert the error if any error occured
      $("#error-message").prepend(
        response["responseJSON"]["error"]
      )
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: 1. Look in the console for errors. 2. console.log(response) to see if you indeed have `responseJSON.error` 3. look in the network console to see what you are receiving

Comment: The `error` handler is only executed when the request fails. Does your server return with a HTTP error (which normally doesn't contain custom user data)?

Comment: *The response is under the form of JsonResponse* - as far as the *request* goes, that's a successful request+response.  The request+response process has not failed.   So you need to check for it in `success:` eg  `success: function(response) { if (response.error) {...`

Comment: More info on what status codes jQuery considers errors here https://stackoverflow.com/q/41577823/2030565

Comment: Thank you all! The following response is from the server: `{error: {account_number: ["Account with this Account number already exists."]}}` and the error function it works, what I can't make it do is to display the error within the response.. so I believe is something wrong here: `$("#error-message").prepend( response["responseJSON"]["error"] )`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem, I wasn't handling the response correctly

```
error: function (response) {
  var error = response ["responseJSON"]["error"];
  $.each(error, function( code, message ) {
     $('#error-message').show().append(message);
  });
}
```